# Linear System Solution Given By a Matrix and It's Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have the following linear systems:
For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, d \in 
 \mathbb{R}^{n}$:
(1) $Ax=b$
(2) $A^{T}x=d$
And I have a set of questions about the realtion between these system, but I just need a help with the first question about it, to get the hang of it and continue with the other ones.
The question is to prove or disprove the statement: If for every $b\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ system (1) has a single solution, then for every $d \in 
 \mathbb{R}^{n}$ system (2) has a single solution.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any specific matrices?

Comment: Hint: if ${\rm det} A \neq 0$ then ${\rm det} A^\top \neq 0$.

Comment: If it has a single solution, then the determinant is non-zero, and the determinant of the transpose is the same, so system (2) also will have a single solution because of that. I feel silly not thinking about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Ax=b$ has a single solution for every b then n=m and also $A^Tx=d$ has a single solution for every d.